# Eigenvector of a sum of two rotation matrices in SO(3)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For some application it turned out that a convex sum of particular rotation matrices in 3D had a real eigenvector. Each rotation matrix had a (different) time dependent rotation angle, but the eigenvector of the sum was not time dependent (at least it did not seem so, this had to be done numerically). It is a very complicated sum so I will not reproduce it here. But it made me start to experiment with sums of rotation matrices, and I have the following question:

For two rotation matrices $R(u_1,\theta_1)$ and $R(u_2,\theta_2)$ in $SO(3)$, with rotation axis $u_i$ and rotation angle $\theta_i$ I want to determine what are the eigenvectors of $R_1+R_2$, in terms of $u_i$ and $\theta_i$. I tried to put this in mathematica but got huge expressions that do not simplify down. 
This does not seem like something too crazy to be interested in, has it been done before?
I tried to write it as
$$
(R_1+R_2)\bar{v} = \lambda \bar{v}
$$
then set $\bar{v}=\bar{u}_i+\bar{w_i}$ where $\bar{u}_i$ is the real eigenvector of $R_i$ and $w_i$ is orthogonal to it. It does not help much though, I just then have to solve
$$
\bar{u}_1+\bar{u}_2 + R_1\bar{w}_1 + R_2\bar{w}_2 = \lambda \bar{v} \ .
$$
I wonder if there is a "nice" expression for the eigenvector, preferably in terms of rotation axis and angles of the matrices? This will help, I suppose, to determine when the eigenvector is independent of the angle of the rotation matrices. I know that when the two rotation axis are the same the eigenvector is the rotation axis. Is it the ONLY case?

Comment: There is no such thing as an eigenvector which is "independent of the angle of the rotation matrices," since the rotation matrix is completely specified by the angle of the rotation matrix.  I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: The rotation matrix is specified by an angle, and by its rotation axis. I should add, 3D rotatoins. The only real eigenvector of a 3D rotation is its rotation axis. I will edit it in :)

Comment: It's very odd to add rotation matrices. It would be much more common to multiply them (equivalent to composition). Why are you adding rotation matrices?

Comment: Yeah there seems to be very little information about it. It came up when evaluating unital maps, in general they are a convex sum of unitary operators. These kind of things come up very often in physics, but I guess not many people have wondered about the sum of general matrices.

Comment: Chapter VII of Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* have some inequalities that give you some description of what's going on here

Comment: I have seen some upper and lower bounds before for different types of matrices, but it was not applicable. But thanks I will try to get a hold of it.

Comment: Bhatias Matrix Analysis has useful inequalities but there is no answer for this particular problem.

Comment: The question is now posted also on MathOverflow: [Eigenvectors of sum of SO(3) matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309906).